# How to specify rectangle stroke only on left and right in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to have rectangle that should have stroke only on left and right side(not on upper and lower side). How can I do it ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't - a rectangle only has a single stroke thickness.  A `Border`, though, uses a thickness structure that can have different thickness on each side:

```
<Border BorderThickness="5,0,5,0" BorderBrush="Black" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that was simple. Answered.

Answer (score 0):

you could use StrokeDashArray.

alternating between strokes at each vertex.

not perfect solution but with a bit of tweeking has worked well for me.